# Problem of integral for the marginal density function

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

It is given the joint probability density function of two random variables X and Y

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi \ln(2)}{1+x^2+y^2} & \text{if } x^2 + y^2 \le 1,\\
0 & \text{if } x^2 + y^2 > 1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

the goal is to calculate the marginal density function of X. So I start from Y's integral:

$$f_X(x)=\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{\pi \ln(2)}{1+x^2+y^2} dy$$

Please help me to calculate this integral.

Comment: Let $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}\,t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the formula $$\int_{0}^a \frac{k}{b^2+y^2}dy=\frac{k}{b}\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$